# Spring integration gateway routing

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a problem with spring integration basically I'am trying to create chain which will invoke 1 of several services and returns result as reply to chain gateway for further processing.

```
<int:chain input-channel="inputChannel" output-channel="outputChannel">
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="temporalPayload" expression="payload"/>
        <int:header name="matcher" value="other" />
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int:gateway request-channel="routerChannel" reply-channel="replyChannel" error-channel="errorChannel"/>
    <int:transformer expression="headers.temporalPayload"/>
</int:chain>

<int:router input-channel="routerChannel" expression="headers.matcher.matches('(test)|(test2)')?headers.matcher:'other'" >
    <int:mapping value="test1" channel="channel1"/>
    <int:mapping value="test2" channel="channel2"/>
    <int:mapping value="other" channel="channel3" />
</int:router>

<int:service-activator input-channel="channel1" output-channel="replyChannel" ref="service1" method="handle"/>
<int:service-activator input-channel="channel2" output-channel="replyChannel" ref="service2" method="handle"/>
<int:service-activator input-channel="channel3" output-channel="replyChannel" ref="service3" method="handle"/>
```

Problem that gateway does not receive reply to channel "replyChannel" from service-activator. What I'am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn on DEBUG logging level for `org.springframework.integration` category and observe how your message travels.

On the other hand, in most cases you don’t need that `reply-Channel` on the gateway and just rely on the `replyChannel` header populated by the gateway. In this case you even have to remove the `output-Channel` on the `service-activator`s.

There might be some subscriber for your `repjyChannel` who steals messages for the Gateway.

You can try without `reply-Channel` or investigate logs as I suggested above.

Comment: I turned on DEBUG logging and found out that in fact another chain was subscribed to service-activator output channel and 'steals' gateway messages. Thank you for your help.